# Spring FactoryBean usage

Tags: java, spring

I have an application in which I would like to be able to switch DAO implementations based on a value in a properties file. The Spring FactoryBean interface looks like it would work nicely in that I could provide the DAO via the FactoryBean inside of which I can do the work of switching based on the property value.

The last paragraph of [this](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean) springsource blog post, however, mentions this caveat:

> One important takeaway here is that it is the FactoryBean, not the factoried object itself, that lives in the Spring container and enjoys the lifecycle hooks and container services. The returned instance is transient - Spring knows nothing about what you've returned from getObject() , and will make no attempt to exercise any lifecycle hooks or anything else on it.

My DAO objects contain the Spring annotations `@Repository` and `@Transactional`. In light of the above paragraph will these annotations be ignored if I return the DAO implementation via the FactoryBean? If so, what is a good way to make sure Spring is managing the bean returned by the FactoryBean?

**Edit:** Seems that most people are offering alternate configuration solutions to the problem. While I am open to these suggestions (and will upvote them if they are good), my question actually has to do with proper FactoryBean usage and I will mark a correct answer based on those questions.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
public interface FooDao {
   // ...
}

@Repository("firstFooDao")
public class FirstFooDao  implements FooDao {
   //...
}

@Repository("secondFooDao")
public class SecondFooDao  implements FooDao {
   //...
}
```

You can create a configuration class to return the appropiate impelementation based on a placeholder (in this example is `foo`):

```
@Configuration
public class FooDaoConfiguration {

    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public FooDao fooDao() {
        return beanFactory.getBean(foo, FooDao.class);
    }

}
```

Then you can switch implementations in a properties file:

```
#foo=firstFooDao
foo=secondFooDao
```

This way, both of your implementations are managed by spring -it is not like the example in the docs you linked, where the returned object is constructed using a non-spring factory. In this case all the beans are instantiated by spring. The configuration class chooses one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property placeholders in the `class` attribute of a bean, so if you have a sensible naming convention you could have something like

```
<bean id="customerDao" class="com.example.dao.${dao.type}.CustomerDao">
```

instead of using a factory bean.

Comment: This is no better than changing the class attribute in `spring.xml` itself. I mean what's the point in introducing a property, configuring the properties file and the post-processor and leaving everyone who opens the xml to wonder what's the current `${dao.type}` in effect.

Comment: @Ravi "I would like to be able to switch DAO implementations based on a value in a properties file" - even if you went for a factory bean approach you'd still have to look in the properties file to find out what dao type is in effect.

Comment: No, with `FactoryBean` you would do something like `<bean id="encrypter" class="my.package.MessageDigestFactoryBean" p:digestAlgorithm="md5" />`. (MD5 encryption in effect)

Answer (score 0):

Create your DAO instance declarations in Spring context as usual using @Component or by XML. Assuming they all inherit a common Interface, then by you can later collect them all using a List. See this link for more info on this type collection mechanism:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation

For example, in your DAOFactory:

```
@Component
class MyCarDAOFactory implements ApplicationContextAware,FactoryBean<CarDAO> {

// Getters and Setters for the ApplicationContextAware interface..
ApplicationContext ctx;
// ...

  // This will place any class that implements CarDAO from Spring Context.
  @Inject
  List<CarDAO> carDaoEntries;

  // This method returns a CarDAO as classified by its Name property specified in 
  // a property placeholder value ( should it have been set in Spring context 
  // via a PropertyPlaceholder)
  public CarDAO getObject() {
   final String val = ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("MY_PROPERTY_KEY");
      return CollectionUtils.find(carDaoEntries, new Predicate() {

        public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
            return ((CarDAO) object).getName().startsWith(val);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Now, there may be a more elegant/ simple solution to this type of problem so if anyone can
chime one in, then please do so!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot: AbstractFactoryBean usage

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

enum ParsersConst {
    bofafactory, jpmfactory, wellsforgofactory
}

interface Parser {
    String readFromFile(String file);

    void setKey(String key);

    String getKey();
}

class JPM implements Parser {
    private String key;

    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From JPM Parser");
        // LOGIC to read file data
        return "JPM";
    }

    @Override
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;

    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

class Bofa implements Parser {
    private String key;

    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From Bofa Parser");
        // LOGIC to read file data
        return "BOFA";
    }

    @Override
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;

    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

class WellsForgo implements Parser {
    private String key;

    @Override
    public String readFromFile(String file) {
        System.out.println("From Wellsforgo Parser");
        // LOGIC to read file data
        return "WellsForgo";
    }

    @Override
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;

    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

class ParserCreator {
    private Map<ParsersConst, Parser> parserMap;

    public Parser createParser(ParsersConst parsConst) {
        Parser parser = parserMap.get(parsConst);
        if (parserMap.get(parsConst) != null) {
            return parser;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Parser");
    }

    public void setParserMap(Map<ParsersConst, Parser> parserMap) {
        this.parserMap = parserMap;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
class ParserFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<Parser> {
    private Parser parser;
    private String key;

    public ParserFactory(Parser parser, String key) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return parser.getClass();
    }

    @Override
    protected Parser createInstance() throws Exception {
        parser.setKey(key);
        return parser;
    }
}

@Configuration
class ParserConfig {

    @Bean
    public ParserFactory jpmfactory() {
        ParserFactory factory = new ParserFactory(jpm(), "XMYMK1@KML");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ParserFactory bofafactory() {
        ParserFactory factory = new ParserFactory(bofa(), "A2344567");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ParserFactory wellsforgofactory() {
        ParserFactory factory = new ParserFactory(wellsforgo(), "ABC345AAD");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Parser bofa() {
        return new Bofa();
    }

    @Bean
    public Parser wellsforgo() {
        return new WellsForgo();
    }

    @Bean
    public Parser jpm() {
        return new JPM();
    }
}

@Component
public class StaticFacotryDemo implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Parser parser = (Parser) context.getBean(ParsersConst.jpmfactory.toString());
        System.out.println(parser.getKey() + " " + parser.readFromFile("hello"));
    }

}
```